# Running CSS Rectangle Property in Different Browsers

Tags: css

I am using this code

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

For creating rectangular shape using CSS. It works fine in Mozilla FireFox but it is not working in Internet Explorer or other browsers. If you have any solution please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to rounded-rectangles?

Comment: You mean, a rectangular shape with rounded corners, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /*for webkit based browsers..*/
```

In IE9, border-radius works (to the best of my knowledge, I believe)..

**For previous versions of IE**, just go through this link : http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers
and this: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

Copy-pasting from that website:

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

You can find the file here : http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Saf3-4 */
border-radius: 15px; /* Opera 10.5, Saf5, Chrome */
```

For IE: Until IE 9 it is not supported